# display all hidden files in the current directory not in the parent directory

Tags: linux, shell, hidden-files

I need to display all hidden files in the current directory but I dont want to see hidden files in the parent directory. I used echo command for it but so far I cant get rid of hidden files in parent directory.

My code is:
`echo $(ls .* --ignore='*')`

The output is:

```
.bash_history 
.bash_logout 
.bashrc .profile 
.: 
..: 
.cache: 
.config: 
.gnupg: 
.loc                           
al:
```

Comment: ls -a | egrep '^\.'

Comment: Wouldn't ```ls -d .*``` solve your problem?

Comment: Try `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*'` as well.

Comment: Given code follows _Useless use of echo_ [style](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Answer (score 0):

This lists only hidden files:

```
ls -d .?*
```